# Android Toolbar popup menu WindowLeaked when orientation change

Tags: android, rotation, toolbar

I spent the day on this one:

I use a normal Toolbar.

-- in MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar_main, menu);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.test1:
           test1();
           return true;

        case R.id.test2:
           test2();
           return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

-- menu_toolbar_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_test1"
        support:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_test2"
        support:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>
```

- I have different items and some appear in a Popup menu (support:showAsAction="never").
- **My problem: If I open the Popup menu and i rotate the screen, then I get a WindowLeaked exception.**

E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.test.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView...

- I tried to hide the Popup menu in the onPause(), onStop, onDestroy, but it's not working...

Note: The only answer I found on Internet is the android:configChanges="orientation" trick. But I don't want to do this.

Thank you !

Comment: From the information that you have shown here is hard to understand/help you. Could please provide some more detail? By the way, code would be great.

Comment: I updated with code